# Which apps support to open and convert JPEG XL (.jxl) pictures?

Tags: software-recommendation, convert, photo-management, photo, jpeg

[JPEG XL (.jxl)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XL) is the next-generation, general-purpose image compression codec by the JPEG committee (more info you can find [on jpegxl.info](https://jpegxl.info/)). Which apps/programs can open and convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far following [apps support JPEG XL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XL#Existing_support):

**Viewers**

- Geeqie – Recent [commit](https://github.com/BestImageViewer/geeqie/commit/02860865e3391bc14114894c7f1df8dbf19dfca0) adds JPEG XL support.
- [gThumb](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gthumb/) (Linux image viewer) from version 3.11.3 onwards as [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.gThumb) or [with unofficial UbuntuHandbook PPA](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/tag/jpeg-xl/):

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
- [XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/) – closed-source image viewer (but up to 0.99.1 JXL support limited to Windows)
- [Gwenview](https://apps.kde.org/gwenview/) (KDE Application)
- [PhotoQt Image Viewer](https://photoqt.org/get)
- [nomacs](https://nomacs.org/download/) - Image Lounge
- [qimgv](https://github.com/easymodo/qimgv) - Image viewer. Fast, easy to use. Optional video support.
- [digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/) - Advanced open-source digital photo management application, [settings see here](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/digikam/#digikamjxlsupport).
- [PicView](https://github.com/Ruben2776/PicView) - Fast Picture Viewer
- [Qt **plug-in qt-jpegxl-image-plugin**](https://github.com/novomesk/qt-jpegxl-image-plugin) to allow **Qt** and **KDE** based applications to read/write JXL images.

**Browsers**

- [Palemoon](https://www.palemoon.org) (from [version 31.4.0](https://www.palemoon.org/releasenotes-archived.shtml) onwards)

**Browsers with activation**

- Firefox (see [Tutorial](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/firefox/)), Chrome, Edge, Opera, [Brave](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/brave/#bravejpegxltutorial=)

**Converters**

- [libjxl](https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl) – JPEG XL Reference implementation
- [MConverter](https://mconverter.eu/) – online media converter
- [Squoosh](https://squoosh.app/) – WebAssembly-based image converter
- [jpegxl.io](https://jpegxl.io/)

**Other:**

- **Thunderbird** (Email client): [To enable JPEG XL support](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/thunderbird/#jpegxlsupport): Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> General: Click on button Config Editor: Manually set image.jxl.enabled to true.
- [Photostack](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/photostack/) - Open-source batch photo editor
- [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) – Official JPEG XL support added in version 12.25.
- [darktable](https://www.darktable.org/) since [version 4.2](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/releases/tag/release-4.2.0) - Open source photography workflow application and raw developer
- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) – With 2.10.32 the JPEG XL file format support was backported from the 2.99.8 development release, so far only with import ability ([unofficial PPA for Ubuntu 21.10+](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/gimp), `sudo apt install libjxl-gimp-plugin` [needed to get JPEG XL support](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/06/gimp-2-10-32-released-bigtiff-jpeg-xl/)).
  The [libjxl](https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl) repository includes a **plugin** for 2.10+.
  There is [another plugin](https://github.com/novomesk/gimp-jpegxl-plugin) for **development GIMP** 2.99.
- [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) – toolkit for raster graphics processing
- [FFmpeg](https://wikiless.org/wiki/FFmpeg) – multimedia framework, via [libjxl](https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl)
- [Qt / KDE apps](https://kde.org/announcements/frameworks/5/5.89.0/) - via KImageFormats
- [Squoosh App](https://squoosh-desktop.vercel.app/) - Multiplatform desktop app to optimize, resize, compress and convert your images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [full list of all softwares and services that support JPEG XL](https://jpegxl.io/), as of November 2021. This list (and the linked tutorials) are authored by me, as part of a project to create an ecosystem platform around the format:

**Browsers:**

1. Chrome (behind a flag, [tutorial](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/chrome/))
2. Firefox (behind a flag in the Nightly version, [tutorial](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/firefox/))
3. Edge (behind a flag, [tutorial](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/edge/))
4. Opera (behind a flag, [tutorial](https://jpegxl.io/tutorials/opera/))

**CDNs:**

1. Only Cloudinary, [on request](https://cloudinary.com/blog/cloudinary_supports_jpeg_xl)

**Toolkits, Libraries:**

2. ExifTool (metadata)
3. Exiv2 (metadata)
4. KDE Frameworks
5. Library for PHP (decoding)

**Converters**

1. libvips (library)
2. jpegxl.io (support library & online conversion, client-side)
3. Squoosh (online conversion, client-side)
4. ImageMagick (toolset)
5. FileStar (conversion software)

**Viewers:**

1. Geeqie (*)
2. GwenView (*)
3. gThumb (*)
4. ImageGlass (*)
5. [IrfanView](https://www.reddit.com/r/jpegxl/comments/mzvjuf/jpegxl_in_irfanview/)
6. nomacs (*)
7. PhotoQt (*)
8. PhotoStack
9. PicView
10. XnView

** Should work with Ubuntu, either natively or with a third-party installer.

Edit: Added authorship notice!

Comment: Looks like you're the author of the linked articles.  Please disclose your affiliation, *in the answer*, in order for your post not to be considered spam.  For more info please see [How not to be a spammer](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Oh, sorry! Will do. Thanks for the headups!